# SVN commit failed

Tags: svn

```
D:\svnroot>svn commit -m "Type your justification here" --username svnu --password test

svn: Authorization failed
```

I'm sure the username/password is correct(in `conf/password`),is it necessary to have exactly that user on the remote svn server?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure the username/password is correct(in conf/password),is it necessary to have exactly that user on the remote svn server?

`conf/password` or `conf/passwd`? The correct file is `passwd`. As for having "exactly" that user on the remove SVN server... I don't know what you mean? The username has to be correct, but it doesn't need a user account.

Note that SVN is probably case sensitive when it comes to usernames and passwords.

Comment: Yes it's a typo,should be `passwd`,but even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it says that authorization, not authentication, failed. Your username and password were accepted, but SVN doesn't think that that user has write permission.

Assuming you're using svnserve (since if it were apache the error would mention a HTTP status code):

- check that `svnserve` wasn't started with the read-only option
- check that `svnserve.conf` has `auth-access = write`
- if an authz file is in use, check that it lists your user